# Shrink one column's height to content and stretch the other to the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We have a two-column layout, with a blue and a green column. It should behave after the following conditions:

- Both columns have equal width.
- The blue column height shall be determined on its content height, without giving any regard to the green column.
- The green column should always have the same height as the blue one. So the height of the green column should be entirely determined by the height of the blue column / the content of the blue column.
- The gray image positioned within the green column should stretch to the height of the green column but preserving dimensions.

Is there a way of achieving this using flexbox or other CSS techniques?

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes there is. Show some code of what you have tried

Comment: I'll create a fiddle asap. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this, where you use a absolute position wrapper in the right column, which will always keep same size as the left, and if to much content, it scrolls

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container, .left-column {
  display: flex;
}
.left-column {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #69f;
}
.left-items {  
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.right-column {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: #6f6;
}
.right-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px; top: 5px;
  right: 5px; bottom: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left-column">

    <div class="left-items">    
Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    
    <div class="left-items">    
      Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    
    <div class="left-items">    
      Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    
    <div class="left-items">    
      Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    
    <div class="left-items">    
      Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    
    <div class="left-items">    
      Content will push height here<br>
    </div>    

  </div>

  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="right-wrapper">
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
      Content will scroll here<br>
    </div>    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `float: left` the blue column, and use `position: absolute` on the green column, setting `right : 0` on it so that it pulls to the right of the container. For the image using the full height of its container and maintaining proportions you can use a div with `background-image` and `background-position: cover`.

Here is an example of a simple html structure and its css:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-container">
    <div class="blue-col">
        <div class="blue-col-content">
            Variable height content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="green-col">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.blue-col {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blue-col-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 500px;
}

.green-col {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.green-col .img {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('http://cdn.blessthisstuff.com/imagens/stuff/porsche-356-outlaw.jpg');
}
```

Here is [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eduguerra/uLppyr0x/) of the solution.